# how to find previous dropdown value based on class name

Tags: jquery, selector

i have a button and on the click event i want to read the value from a dropdown based on a class name.  I want to grab the previous instance of this class.

i know i can do this to get the exact previous value but how do you add the class condition?

```
var teamId = $(this).prev().val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>[prevUntil](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) is doing exactly what you ask: `$(this).prevUntil('some_selector')`</s>

Scratch that. [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) allows you to pass in selector. You can also return the nearest matched sibling with `:first`: `.prevAll('.my_class:first')`.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qrp3/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can add a selector as parameter of the prev() method.
So something like

```
var teamId = $(this).prev(".myclass").val();
```

should work.

Comment: Actually, it won't go farther than one element from the current one. It's just additional filter for standard `prev` behaviour.